# Grails simple plugin "not a valid plugin"

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

So the cache (ivy) finds my simple test plugin repository and downloads it.
Then when it goes to build it says "not a valid plugin".

Plugin file structure

```
  >grails-app
  >lib
  >scripts
  >src
  >test
  >web-app
  -application.properties
  -SltDbGrailsPlugin.groovy
```

My plugin config file (SltDbGrailsPlugin.groovy) looks like this

```
class SltDbGrailsPlugin{

        def version="0.1"
        def grailsVersion="2.2>*";
}
```

My properties file is

```
app.grails.version=2.2.0
app.name=SltDb
```

and in my BuildConfig.groovy is

```
compile ":SltDb:0.1";
```

which I think is all right. What are some common reasons why a plugin is "not valid"?

Answer (score 0):

What version of grails? I assume 2.x because of ivy-cache.. Perhaps the plugin is cached in the grails application's target folder in a corrupted state. Delete the target folder and try to build.

```
 rmdir <application>/target /s /q
```

This will force the grails build script to obtain a fresh copy of the plugin from the ivy-cache.
You could also try uninstalling the plugin in the application and then re-installing it.

```
grails uninstall-plugin StlDb
grails install-plugin StlDb
```

Finally you could try "inline" style for the plugin (this is really really useful when your plugin is changing a lot but the version is not being updated).

```
Remove StlDb plugin reference
<application>/application.properties
#plugins.stldb=1.0.0

Inline the plugin in BuildConfig
<application>/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
grails.plugin.location.'StlDb' = "/local/path/to/source/for plugin/StlDb"
```